# what is the meaning of this python code: <L in struct.pack("<L",self.src)

Tags: python, sockets, networking, sniffer

My problem is to understand the meaning of: `<L` in this python code:

```
self.src_address = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L",self.src))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment

Comment: Reading is ***such*** a hassle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format-string `"<L"` in the expression `struct.pack("<L",self.src)` means that `pack` interpretes the value in `self.src` as little-endian ordered unsigned long value. The [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is a convention, which determines in which direction a sequence of bits are interpreted as a number: from (Big-endian) left to right, or from (Little-endian) right to left.

Afterwards the unsigned long number is conterted to standard dotted-quad string representation via `socket.inet_ntoa()`

Comment: what men little-endian ? please give me sample

Comment: Added that detail to the answer.